# All usb ports randomly disconnect

Tags: windows-7, usb

Recently my USB ports disconnect randomly and stays disconnected until I pull the cable out and reconnect it which temporarily keeps my devices connected.

I've tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling drivers;
- setting advanced power option "USB Selective suspend settings" as disabled;
- looking for USB-3 compatibility issues from BIOS (but I don't have USB-3 ports);
- scanning for malware.

Problem still persists.

Specs:
MB- Gigabyte GA-F2A55M-DS2
System Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model: To be filled by O.E.M.
BIOS: BIOS Date: 06/26/13 14:58:57 Ver: 04.06.05
Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) X4 760K Quad Core Processor      (4 CPUs), ~3.8GHz
Memory: 8192MB RAM
Page File: 3768MB used, 28830MB available

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issues, and the issue would be the fact that the power delivered to the USB ports in question is less than a certain threshold, after which the port itself decides that can't be good, and disconnects. An obvious cause could be overloading one USB port from the computer mainbord (by using a USB hub), but the USB port on the main bord could be having an issue just supplying power for any device in fact. So, that would mean the mainbord is malfunctioning, although everything seems OK.